# не могу сгенерировать приложение из за ошибки

Tags: java, android

ошибка такая:

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/BackStackRecord$Op.class
```

мой gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "бла бла"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 19
        versionName "2.2.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }}}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.github.stankoutils:app:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.vk:androidsdk:1.6.8'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    compile 'me.srodrigo:androidhintspinner:1.0.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.jaeger.ninegridimageview:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.0'
    compile 'de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    compile 'fr.avianey.com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему некоторые ваши зависимости уже содержат в себе v4 библиотеку поддержки. Вам надо исключить её из этих либ при сборке [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30806952/3212712):

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

или просто удалив эту либу, т.к. она уже есть

```
//надо это удалить
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
```

Comment: Не помогло, пишет ту же ошибку

Comment: @sviter-pro, попробуйте добавить исключение молуля ко всем либам

Comment: Тоже не помогло

Comment: @sviter-pro, если вы не можете найти проблему иначе - создайте пустой проект и начинайте по очереди добавлять зависимости. После каждого добавления собирайте проект - в какой-то момент оно выдаст вам вашу ошибку и вы поймёте что именно вызывает вашу проблему

Comment: Логично...попробую

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте папку `libs`, похоже что там у вас лежит копия `com.android.support:support-v4`. Удалите ее оттуда.

Comment: У меня нет такой папки